# Locale-independent Text function in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to format dates in excel, and I'm trying to use the `TEXT` formula. The problem is that Excel's intepretation of the arguments changes when the locale changes.

For example: if I have a date in cell A1, that i'd like to convert to text, in the year-month-day-format, I have to use `=TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")` if my PC has an English-language locale, but `=TEXT(A1, "jjjj-MM-tt")` (I kid you not, the `M` has to be upper case) if it has a German-language locale. This makes the document unportable. (The second argument is plain text and therefore not converted when changing locale.)

Remarks:

- This is just an example, I know I could do the long `=YEAR(A1) & "-" & TEXT(MONTH(A1), "00") & "-" & TEXT(DAY(A1), "00")` in this case. I'm wondering about the more general case.
- The date should not just be *displayed* in a certain format, it should actually be a string. For someone viewing the file this doesn't make a difference, but when using it in other formulas, it does.
- I could write a UDF in VBA to solve the issue, but I cannot use VBA in this document.
- I do not care about changing the names of the months etc. It's fine, if the name of the month is June or Juni depending on the locale.
- I want to stress that the issue occurs due to the PC's locale - not due to the GUI language of the MS Office version. In the example above, Excel's GUI and formulas were in English in both examples; I just changed the locale on the machine.

Many thanks

Comment: Can't you use the inbuild format `yyyy-mm-dd;@` on `A1`? Wouldn't that make the file portable?

Comment: That would _display_ the date in the correct format, but the underlying value, when referencing it, would still be an Excel Datetime number. I want to use it in another formula, and that formula needs the date as a string.
I'll edit the question to make clear it's not only about presenting it to a viewer in a certain format.

Comment: How about editing those other formulas so that they rely on real dates rather than text strings? Then you could use formatting for the display.

Comment: @Ron, yes, I agree that would be the best solution; it's weird to have a function take a string argument if it's not absolutely necessary. However, unfortunately, I'm not in the position to change these function definitions and need to use them as given.

Comment: I think this problem would be worth a feature request to MS (eg. something like `TEXT2()` with locale-independent parameters, or an optional prefix to the parameter like the language-code for date display as described [here](https://excel.tips.net/T003299_Specifying_a_Language_for_the_TEXT_Function.html)). It took me half an hour to debug why some formulas in a workbook i build on a german locale returned `#VALUE` failures after opening the workbook in Luxembourg: the german version auf `TEXT()` accepts `"Standard"` as second parameter whereas the Lux. version needed `"General"`...

Comment: Depending on the target clients (closed group?) one could also deploy an UDF in an add-in. Also, see this great answer on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/730371/how-to-prevent-excel-to-use-the-os-regional-settings-for-date-patterns-in-formul

Answer (score 8):

Here is a slightly cheaty method:  Use a `VLOOKUP` on a value that will change based on your System Language - for example `TEXT(1,"MMMM")`

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(1,"MMMM"),{"January","yyyy-MM-dd";"Januar","jjjj-MM-tt"},2,FALSE)
```

In English:  `Text(1,"MMMM") = "January"`, so we do a `VLOOKUP` on the Array below to get "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
"January" , "yyyy-MM-dd" ;
"Januar"  , "jjjj-MM-tt"
```

Auf Deutsche, `Text(1,"MMMM") = "Januar"`, also wir machen einen `SVERWEIS` auf dem Array oben, um "jjjj-MM-tt" zu erhalten!  :)

Then, just use that in your `TEXT` function:

```
=TEXT(A1, VLOOKUP(TEXT(1,"MMMM"),{"January","yyyy-MM-dd";"Januar","jjjj-MM-tt"},2,FALSE))
```

Obviously, the main reason this works is that `TEXT(1,"MMMM")` is valid for both German and English.  If you are using something like Filipino (where "Month" is "Buwan") then you might find some issues finding a mutually intelligible formatting input.

Comment: It's definitely very creative! :) It's a huge pain to use, but it might be my only option. Many thanks!

Comment: This is a clever idea. I would adapt it by placing the options in a Table rather than hard-coded in the TEXT formula. Then as I encountered another needed language, I could add a row to the Table.

Comment: @JonPeltier You could probably also drop the formula into a Defined Name (or a Named Cell in the same Worksheet as your suggested table), so that you can call it in your Formulae with something like `[DateFormat]` (i.e. `=TEXT(A1, [DateFormat])`) if it's going to be used a lot throughout the workbook.

Answer (score 3):

I found another possibility. It is not perfect in all cases (see below) but it also works with number formats to be locale independent. As I have the same issue with mixed language versions.
For this you make your own function in vba. Open the developer tools with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and create a new module file. Inside the module file paste something like this:

```
Function FormatString(inputData, formatingString As String) As String

    FormatString = Format(inputData, formatingString)

End Function
```

Then you can use it in cell formulas with english formating strings. Like:

```
= FormatString(A1; "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Advantage: It also works with number formats:

```
= FormatString(A1; "00.00")
```

In case (like Germany) your decimal separator is not a `.`

**Drawbacks:**

1 Not identical to `TEXT` function

this doesn't always work with date formatting as maybe expected and not exactly the same as the `TEXT` function:

```
FormatString(1; "MMMM")
```

does not return "January" but "December" because the 1 is taken as a date. Which is something like 31.12.1899.

2 Has to be saved with macros

You have to save the file as *.xlsm for this to work

Comment: Many thanks for that answer. Yes, using VBA the sky is the limit ;) But as I mentioned in my question, I can't write a user-defined-function in VBA for this document. For other people landing on this question, it might be feasible, however

Comment: @ElRudi Yes that was also my reasoning. Because I landed on the page having the same problems. And finally I came up with this solution as I was working on a macro project anyway. But this is a problem for me because many clients have mixed environments with english and german excel (preference of the user).

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Note (1): this answers only the case for locale-independent TEXT to format numbers with decimal symbols and digit grouping symbols. For date formatting, see [Chronocidal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56947815/243373).</sub>
<sub>Note (2): this answer does not use VBA functions, which would require enabling macros. Enabling macros may not be possible depending on the company's security policy. If enabling macros is an option, [Uwe Hafner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61457791/243373) would be easier.</sub>

---

You can detect the decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol as follows. Enter the number `1` in a specific cell (e.g. `A1`) and the number `1000` in another cell (e.g. `A2`).

- Decimal symbol: `=IF(TEXT(INDIRECT("A1"),"0,00")="001",".",",")`
- Digit grouping symbol<sup>1</sup>: `=IF(TEXT(INDIRECT("A2"),"#,###")="1000,",".",",")`

This is assuming that the decimal symbol is either `.` or `,` and the digit grouping symbol is either `,` or `.` respectively. This will not detect unusual digit grouping symbols like   (space) or `'` (apostrophe).

With this information, you can set up a cell (or cells) with a formula that results in the format code you need to apply.

Suppose you need to format a number to two decimal digits and using the digit grouping symbol. You can assume that if the decimal symbol is `.` then the digit grouping symbol will be `,` and vice versa. You can do the following:

- A1: `1`
- A2 (the formatting string): `=IF(TEXT(INDIRECT("A1"),"0,00")="001","#,##0.00","#.##0,00")`
- A3 (contains an arbitrary number you wish to format)
- A4 (the formatted number): `=TEXT(A3,A2)`

---

Technical note: the `INDIRECT` function is used intentionally because it is a *volatile* function. This guarantees that the formatting string and anything dependent on it is recalculated even if no data changed in the Excel document. If `INDIRECT` is not used, Excel caches results and will not recalculate the formatting string when the Excel document is opened on a PC with different locale settings.

<sub>1 - Also known as *Thousands separator*</sub>

Comment: I tried reproducing this, and only get an error #VALUE! in a german Excel Version (i.e. the decimal symbol is a ",")

Comment: @Servus Yeah, I've noticed problems with my solution as well when the language of the Excel version differs (not only the locale in other words). It's a drag :/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of potential formats and try them out using (here for cell B2) `=IF(IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(DATE(2020,10,24),B2))=DATE(2020,10,24),FALSE),B2,"")`
Then you can select the usable date format (e.g. with FILTER) and refer to that.

Comment: Disclaimer: I do not want to mess around with my current locale, so please test it yourself  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In every Excel file with this problem, I place the following cell:

```
=IFS(
  TEXT(1;"YYYY")<>"YYYY";"EN";
  TEXT(1;"JJJJ")<>"JJJJ";"DE";
  TEXT(1;"aaaa")<>"aaaa";"IT";
  TRUE;"other language, insert more checks"
)
```

I then give it a name, like "rngDateLanguage" (to the left of the formula bar).
Depending on whether I have multiple fields which require formatting, I either place the following in its own cell (rngDateFormat) and reference the Cell in TEXT([@value];rngDateFormat). I create as many different of these cells, as I have different formats inside the file:

```
=IFS(
  rngDateLanguage = "DE"; "TT.MM.JJJJ";
  rngDateLanguage = "EN"; "DD.MM.YYYY";
  rngDateLanguage = "IT"; "gg.MM.aaaa"
)
```

Or integrate the ifs directly into a TEXT([@value]; IFS(...)) as @ElRudi suggested.

Edit: if you can, prefer using right click / format. This scenario is needed when you have to concatenate the date into texts.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I suppose it could be optimised with something like `= Text([@Value]; ifs(rngDateLanguage = "DE";"JJJJ-MM-TT";rngDateLanguage = "EN"; "YYYY-MM-DD"; "aaaa-MM-gg"))` (untested)

Comment: Thanks @ElRudi, I'll update the formulas to use IFS instead of IF, as well as provide the optimization.

Answer (score -2):

The easy fix, whether directly custom formatting a cell or using TEXT(), is to use a country code for a language you know the proper formatting codes for.

For instance, I am in the US, have a US version of Excel, and am familiar with its date code formats. So I'd want to use them and to ensure they "come out" regardless of anyone's Windows or Excel version, or the country they are in, I'd do it like the following (for TEXT(), let's say, but it'd be the same idea in custom formatting):

```
=TEXT(A1,[$-en-US]"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

The function would collect the value in A1, ask Excel to treat it as a date, Excel would and would say fine, it's cool (i.e.: the value is, say, 43857 and not "horse") because it is a positive number which is a requirement for anything to be treated as a date, and let the function move on to rendering it as a date in the manner prescribed. Rather than giving an #ERROR! as it would for "horse" or -6.

The function would then read the formatting string and see the language code. It would then drop the usual set of formatting codes it loaded upon starting up and load in the formatting codes for English ("en") and in particular, US English ("US"). The rest of the string uses codes from that set so it would interpret them properly and send an appropriate string back to TEXT() for it to display in the cell (and pass on to other formulas if such exist).

I have no way to test the following, but I assume that if one were to use a format that displayed day of the week names or month names, they would be from the same language set. In other words, Excel would not think that even though you specified a country and language that you still wanted, say, Dutch or Congolese month names. So that kind of thing would still need addressed, but would be an easy fix too just involving, say, a simple lookup one could add though it'd be "fun" setting up the lookup table for each language one wanted to accomodate...

However, the basic issue that arises with this problem in general, is very, very easily solved with the country codes. They aren't even hard or arcane anymore now that the [$-409] syntax has been replaced with things like [$-en-us] and [$-he-IL] and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joerje, but that's not having the intended effect. The language code works on the OUTPUT, and causes text (like month names) to be in the specified language. It does not cause Excel to understand the INPUT format string in that language.

So, on a German system, the format string must still be specified as 'jjjj-MM-dd', and on an English system it must still be specified 'yyyy-mm-dd', regardless of the presence of a language code. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/di8cnXN) an illustration of what I mean.