# How do I concatenate a date cell (independant of locale) to a string in Excel?

Tags: excel, date

I have a date cell 2020-02-21.

In my mind *CONCAT(A1," my date")* should procude the expected string "2020-02-21 my date".

But no, Excel decides to treat is as a date and convert it to a mumbojumbo number resulting in the output "438562 my date". This **would** be logical if the cell value was formatted as date, but it's a TEXT field (!!).

So now you're probably going to point me to the millions of threads on this site that tell me to use the TEXT function. But here's the deal. The second argument of TEXT expects a format such as "YYYY-mm-dd" which is going to be **LOCALE SPECIFIC**. If I hardcode a format, the file won't work when I pass it to my collegue in spain, or whatever.

It works if I use "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-dd" but that's specific only to Sweden. I've tried the [$-xxx] codes in front of the fromat, but to no avail.

Is there a way to format the date in "YYYY-MM-DD" format without excel caring about the langauge or locale you are using?

Getting utterly frustrated that such a simple task cannot be done easily. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locale-independent Text function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56901270/locale-independent-text-function-in-excel)

Comment: Well, "sort of", but not quite. The VLOOKUP would only work if I specified every location the file was intended to be used in. That is the lookup table would have to be maintained (or a lookup of ALL countries would have to be provided).

I think the easiest solution would be to format the cell as TEXT(A1;B1). People would then have to edit B1 themseleves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: `=CONCATENATE(YEAR(A1),"-",MONTH(A1),"-",DAY(A1)," my date")`

Comment: Perfect, simple and does the job- thanks!

EDIT: There is a caveat to this that breaks it. It will return 2020-1-3 for third of january, I'd want it to be 2020-01-03 instead.

Comment: Try changing MONTH(A1) to TEXT(MONTH(A1), "00")

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted, as it's closest to solving my problem without giving me a severe headache ;)

Comment: It's still locale specific thought, so it's the same as using =TEXT(A1, "YYYY-MM-DD"). How does this answer your question?

Comment: @gouravkr What in that formula is locale-specific?  Functions written in the language of the workbook are not -- they translate when the workbook is opened in a different language.  It is only the formatting strings that would be locale-specific, and they are not present in this formula.

Comment: OK, understood. I thought you wanted the date to be locale independent such that it shows, for example, dd-mm-yyyy in India and mm-dd-yyyy in the US, etc.